# Is it Ok to Add an Addendum to a Resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, recruitment, applications, careers

As most of my one page resume consists of work experience and projects, I feel that my long list of "other skills" such as "google cloud, aws, scrum, kanban ...." could use some backing up by another page which details my exact experience with such skills such as "I got to experience a shift from a using a scrum process at my company to a kanban process, and have experience developing in both processes..." etc.

I just feel that listing all these keywords without mention of them takes away from the credibility of the resume.

Comment: Those sound like good things to include in the cover letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of that should be included as experience under each of the positions where you had that experience, not as an addendum.

Also, write as active participation - "participated in a transition to kanban process...", rather than "experienced" which is more passive

Answer (score 1):

A second page to your resume is just fine. List your skills and any other useful work related experience there. Depending on your length of time spent in the trenches so to speak, it can equal a many paged resume. Just don't waffle or put down "fluff" or "filler" only salient on point info. Best of luck.. T